# How to cast an PSafeArray item into its original type

Tags: c#, delphi, com, delphi-7

I am using an `COM` in `Delphi 7` that was created in `C#` and one of the methods of a class return an array of an type. However, when Delphi imports it, instead of an array of that type I get an `PSafeArray`.

How can I cast the items of that array into its base type?

I've tried to use `SafeArrayGetElement` but I couldn't find a way of casting the item into its original type.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need to do any casting as the SafeArrayGetElement does it for you. An example :

```
var
  Scope : ICOMScope;
  LBound, UBound, I : Integer;
begin
  SafeArrayGetLBound(fMyComObject.Scopes, 1, LBound);
  SafeArrayGetUBound(fMyComObject.Scopes, 1, HBound);
  for i := lBound to Hbound do
  begin
    SafeArrayGetElement(fMyComObject.Scopes, i, Scope);
    //do something with scope
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how Delphi handles the type library interpretation, but a `SAFEARRAY` has an associated type.

If you can view the type library for the C# assembly, you can probably glean the underlying type from there.

If not, you can call `SafeArrayGetVarType` on the array to get its associated type at run-time (this has had problems on `SAFEARRAY`s created by some APIs, though, so you may get garbage back.)

Most likely, though, it is exposed as a `SAFEARRAY` of `VARIANT` where every item is of a "dynamic" type.

Do you know if you can process `VARIANT`s in Delphi?

Comment: Yes Delphi can handle Variants.

The real issue is that I do know the type, but when I try to cast it into it an exception is thrown.

I think all the problem is because the types are defined inside a COM.

Comment: I wonder if /casting/ is not the way to do it. Or is that the general mechanism for getting the value out of a Variant?